# How do I add a prefix to all urls and generically parse that as a kwarg

Tags: django, django-urls

Let's say I have a site where all urls are username specific.

For example /username1/points/list is a list of that user's points.

How do I grab the /username1/ portion of the url from all urls and add it as a kwarg for all views?

Alternatively, it would be great to grab the /username1/ portion and append that to the request as request.view_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider attacking this with [middlware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). Specifically using process_request. This is called *before* the urlresolver is called and you can do pretty much anything to the request (request.path in this case) you want to. You might strip out the username and store it in the request object. Specifics depend (obviously) on the conditions under which you do/do not want to remove the first path component.

**Updated for comment:**
Whichever way you go about it, when you call [reverse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) you have to give it the additional context info -- it can't just automagically figure it out for itself. Django doesn't play any man-behind-the-curtains games -- everything is straight Python and there isn't any global state floating around just off stage. I think this is a Good Thing™.

Comment: This method works great. 

However - I am struggling to get the reverse path component back into the url for reversing urls.  Any suggestions on that given reverse does not have access to the request object to access that user?